# Concurrent updation issue using mongodb with kafka consumers

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have an application with 4 kafka consumers which are making an update operation on mongodb. It is possible that they may attempt to update same record at the same time. I have handled it using syncronized block for updating. It works fine when I am run the application on a single server. But when I run this application on multiple servers for high availability, it fails. And some of the transactions fail to update records because they had fetched the record in the same state.
Can anybody suggest the right approach to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: You have metioned that the kafka consumers might try to update the same record at the same time? I don't think that is a good idea. Anyways, if that's the case, then you should think about using Mongo Locks https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/ . There are other ways but with some flaws.

Comment: I have tried mongo locks, but it slow down the updation process. Is there any other ways to make updation.

Comment: Obviously it will slow it down as only one of the Kafka consumers would be able to write/update to the collection.

Comment: You can keep a field in the collection say, `taken` which would be true if a record is being updated, so basically it would be a lock at record level but if two consumers try to update the record at the exact split second then they both will get the `taken` field as false and hence in this scenario it will fail, although it will be very rare.

Comment: Not sure if you rely on a framework in your application, but the concept of "consumer groups" in Spring Cloud Stream might be the way to go. Within a consumer group only one service will process the message an make an update on MongoDB.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#consumer-groups

Comment: @dbaer Consumer groups would still read messages parallely from multiple partitions of a topic, it doesn't control writes to external systems

Comment: Overall, I would suggest looking at using Kafka Connect instead, though it's not clear what your data looks like